# How to make a table with 2 materials for the top?

Tags: materials

I'm trying to make a round table and I'm still really new to blender.

The table is supposed to use 2 materials for the top, wood for the edges and glass in the middle.

I tried to use the boolean modifier with 2 cylinders and after that didn't work I tried it with filled in circles, which also didn't work.

I hope you can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Some images of the mesh and an image of what you're trying to achieve would help! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. select both faces of the table in face select mode, and press I to inset

[image]

2. edge -> bridge edge loops

[image]

3. extrude individual faces -> S -> 0

[image]

4. select all inner faces (also on the bottom side)

[image]

5. add new material -> glass -> assign

[image]

6. invert selection

[image]

7. add new material -> wood -> assign (e.g. you could get a free wood texture from free blenderkit add-on)

you might get this:

[image]

so go back in edit mode again, in face select mode box select the "rest":

[image]

select your glass material:

[image]

and hit assign

[image]

This works for cycles.

In Eevee you have to use alpha blend as blend mode in the glass material:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you constructing an inner face in this situation :p

Comment: yes, else the glass would break - as every construction worker knows ;) i am just totally disappointed of Blender SE that until now nobody wrote that i cannot use this geometry because it is totally shit... ;) i mean, just hitting F to build a gigantic n-gon - that was just tooooo easy ;)